# Extend/resize boot partition

Tags: boot, 16.04, 18.04, partitioning, mount

Currently i have /dev/sda disk on which i have root partition (as /dev/sda1) and boot (as /dev/sda2)

As my boot partition is only 100MB i need to extend it. Unfortunately i can't add space to disk /dev/sda and i don't have any spare space on /dev/sda so i what i need to do is create new disk and assign it to VM. Then on this new disk i need to create boot partition and somehow make it working.

I tried to do it in that way:

- Created /dev/sdb1 partition
- Copied content from /dev/sda2 (boot) to /dev/sdb1
- Mounted /dev/sdb1 as boot (also changed in fstab to use /dev/sdb1 instead of /dev/sda2)
- Updated grub/Installed grub (update-grub, grub-install /dev/sdb, grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg)
- Replaced values in menu.lst (to use hd1 instead of hd0)
- run grub command and used: root (hd1,0), setup (hd1)

(last 3 steps done both on with chroot as guided here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot and without)

however system still looks for boot partition on /dev/sda and i dont see new kernels during grub phase during boot

Is it even possible to have boot partition on different drive then root partition?
Any of you know how to setup it up?

GPARTED Ubuntu 16:

[/dev/sda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1CH5.png)

[/dev/sdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrjtL.png)

OS vs GRUB Ubuntu 18:

[Picture while booted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnRWu.png)

[GRUB while booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixlJZ.png)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: FYI:  Changing where you have installed grub stage 0 (`grub-install /dev/sdb`) is only useful if you've changed your BIOS/uEFI to refer to sdb as the boot drive.  Yes boot partitions can be on different drives to / partition.

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshots of `gparted` for /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema i just edited my post with gparted pictures. Currently /boot is mounted under /dev/sdb1

Comment: @guiverc same for Ubuntu 18 (attached screenshots) I even did a test and mounted temporarily /dev/sda1 (old boot) on /boot1 and replaced values in menu.lst (groot and root) to hd2,0 (/dev/sdc1 - new boot). And it works what clearly indicates that /dev/sda1 is still a boot partition even after unmounting it and overriding grub.cfg

Comment: I think that you're going about this all wrong. First, sda2 doesn't appear to need more space. You can reduce sda1 if you disagree. Manually editing boot files should not be required. But the bigger problem appears that you're running on USB flash drives, or SD cards... not recommended.

Comment: @heynnema this is a test environment, treat it as 100M

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What's 100M? If you wish to increase sda2, why not just resize sda1, then move/resize sda2? Still don't understand why you need more sda2.

Comment: @heynnema my goal is to migrate boot partition (only boot partition, not root) on another disk and boot from there (new disk)

Comment: I understand your goal... but why? sdb is only 2G flash/SD. Why not just do something like my last comment? Why does boot need more space?

Comment: @heynnema please focus on my goal if you really want to help here :). Boot migration to another disk is the only option in my case.

Comment: To be able to best help, I'd need to understand your reason for needing to increase sda2, or moving it to another flash/SD. sda2 doesn't appear to need more space. If you don't wish to elaborate, then I can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "easy" approach would be to just merge your boot-partition with your root-partition. **Please take note that this might not work (this depends on GRUB) when your root-partition is encrypted or is located on a LVM or software-RAID, your root partition must also be a primary partition.**

For this to work, just do the following in the correct order (**Take special care!**):

- boot your regular system as usual
- unmount your boot-partition
- remount your boot-partition to `/mnt/`
- copy all files from `/mnt/` to `/boot/` via `sudo cp -av /mnt/* /boot/`
- unmount your boot-partition from `/mnt/`
- **do a backup of your partition table and save it on another device**
- delete your old boot partition (via fdisk)
- make your root-partition an active partition (boot-flag via fdisk)
- run `sudo update-grub`
- run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (just `sda` and not `sda1` or `sdaX`)
- delete the mount entry for your old boot partition from `/etc/fstab`
- reboot your system

I've tested this on a fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 VM and it works.

---

**EDIT: Here is a guide to relocate/migrate the entire boot partition to another new partition.**

For this to work, just do the following in the correct order (**Take special care!**):

- boot your regular system as usual
- create a new partition on any volume as you like (It still must be a primary partition! Start at least at Byte 1048576 !), but use the same filesystem and same partition table type as your old boot-partition has used (probably *msdos* partition table and *ext4* filesystem)
- make your new partition an active partition (boot-flag via fdisk)
- format your newly created partition with a filesystem

  - for *ext4* use `sudo mkfs.ext4 -L newboot /dev/sdXY` (`X` is the volume character of the volume where your newly created newboot-partition is located, `Y` is the partition number)
  - I'll call this partition from now on as *newboot*
- mount *newboot* to `/mnt/`
- copy all files from `/boot/` to `/mnt/` via `sudo cp -av /boot/* /mnt/`
- unmount your old boot-partition from `/boot/`
- also unmount your newboot-partition from `/mnt/`
- **do a backup of your partition tables and save these on another device**
- mount your newboot-partition to `/boot/`
- run `sudo update-grub`
- run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` (just `sdX` and not `sdX1` or `sdXY`, `X` is the volume character of the volume where your newly created newboot-partition is located)
- delete your old boot partition (via fdisk)
- adjust your `/etc/fstab` mount entry for your newboot-partition (you probably need to adjust the UUID, to be found with `sudo blkid`)
- double check everything
- reboot
- enter your BIOS
- make sure that your computer boots from the volume where the newboot-partition is located
- save BIOS settings, reboot and hope for the best

I've tested this also on a fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 VM and it works.

Comment: This is not an option in my case. Boot partition needs to be on another disk

Comment: I'll adapt this guide later, it's also possible for another device to boot.

Comment: @Sudoo please take a look at my edited post.

Comment: Hey @paladin, it works but i also needed to update-initramfs afterwards, thanks

Comment: At which moment have you updated the initramfs? I would like to update the guide with this information.

Comment: First i installed grub on /dev/sdb, then updated grub, then updated initramfs @paladin

Comment: Okay, but according to my guide, you had to do `update-grub` first and do `grub-install` after that ^^

Comment: yes, according to your guide update needs to be done before install but i did in both orders and works